# How to auto-tune without getting a metallic sound?

Tags: autotune

I try to auto-tune a vocal track. I want it to sound as natural as possible, and only want to correct the pitch. The problem is that I get a very metallic/computer-sound. I use Antares Auto-Tune. I use the graphical mode where I first track the pitch, and then move the notes up and down to match the correct pitch. Then I change the duration of each note-block to make it sound as natural as possible.

Is Antares Auto-Tune not good for natural auto-tuning, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a tip of a tutor of mine that is really into recording pop music. He uses auto tune in real time when recording. SO he is monitoring the vocals trough the device. That way he already knows which words/syllables will work and which won't.

Then another tip for all this pitch correction stuff. If you need to correct by huge amounts (= half steps or more) it is best to cut out all the noisy phonemes and place them on a separate track. Nosiy phenomes are esse for example (or use 2 channels nd use the side chain monitoring feature of a deesser to isolate the esses on one track). That is because noisy stuff tends to be treated wrong with pitch correct software. Longer tonal phoebes like vocals. Another trick is to automate the correction amount on the vocals. then you can cut the correction on noisy phonemes and increase it on only the syllables you need to correct.

I know it is a lot of work what i told you, but when you just apply the auto tune you won't get commercial like results.

So my workflow is-> But auto tune on with very little correction -> the automate the correction amount so that it cuts out on noisy stuff-> increase the amount on really off tonal phonemes

Good luck

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used Antares, but it has a reputation for creating a more noticeable tuned "effect" sound. Celemony Melodyne has a reputation for a more transparent tuning. (I'm sure you can get transparent tuning with Autotune as well, but it's not as "auto" as the name implies.)

I use Melodyne to tune vocals. But it is far from automatic. It took me over 20hrs working with the software before I felt like I was really enhancing the sound, and not destroying the performance entirely. It's a tool that takes practice. Less is more. And I find that tuning sustained notes closer to the intended note (but not 100%) and leaving the travelling notes before and after the sustained note can help keep the vocal sounding natural.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for a good answer! I'll try Melodyne. The problem with Antares, in my opinion, is that it is too difficult to fine tune the vocals. Using the note blocks, it's pretty easy to auto-tune. It takes about 1 hour per minute of recording. The other tool you've got is the line tool. But tuning linearly isn't making it natural at all.

Comment: I have resolved some really brutal vocal performances (as well as upright bass!) with Melodyne. One singer I was tracking used copious vibrato to mask her pitch problems. Melodyne lets you reduce modulation, as well as shift it closer to the intended note. And I've achieved pretty stellar results. The singer is really impressed by how good she sounds. ;)

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers...

Answer (score 1):

> and then move the notes up and down to match the correct pitch

sounds like the bulk of your problem..

Comment: I agree. These tools are meant to fune-tune pitch, not remap pitch. Ideally the vocalist should be recorded well, hitting these notes on point or closely. It's all about proper source. There's overall a developed complacency with plugins that they'll solve any problem. Unfortunately the OP doesn't state how much correction is being done, but if there's audible artifacting, it seems to be more pitch correction than Anteres and any of these tools are really geared for.

Comment: @Stavrosound I'm talking on average 1/4 of a whole tone.

Answer (score 1):

Three steps.

Lower Retune speed. Set Humanize to 100 and set Formant on. Formant can also make a voice sound younger or older..Sometimes even if you crank the Retune speed to 0 it will still sound natural with formant engaged. You also can try masking it with reverb and a high pass filter as a send.(almost like a telephone effect)